# Do location services work in iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, core-location

I have an iOS app that uses core location and calculates the distance between two points. It outputs the result to a label which works fine when running on an actual device. But when I run it on the simulator, I get nothing. Is it suppose to work on the simulator as I have location services enabled as you can see in the screenshot below?

Thanks for any help.

[image: Settings Screenshot]

Comment: You can either simulate a specific location or use a GPX file to simulate routes.

Comment: Voting to close, this question is already well answered on Stackoverflow

Comment: I need a live feed of the location, not just one location

Comment: As noted by @nathan you can add a GPX route file to your project, then use the Debug menu in Xcode to select that file as a route for the Simulator. The Simulator itself supports loading a pre-defined route (but not a GPX file).